# Android - How to get Logcat logs for specified actions

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I am doing set of steps using Android UIAutomator. I just want to collect logs during these steps.

Now am starting the adb logcat in terminal and running the ui automator seperately. Save the current logs to file before starting another test case.

Is there a way to collect logs for a particular time and clear the logs and start the next test case and collect logs for that test case.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by configurable log tags.

```
Log.d(TAG, message);
```

Specify separate tags for your groups in your tests and then you can easily grab just the ones you want at a time.

```
adb logcat -s "TAGNAME"
```

Run your test through fully so all logs are in the logcat then add the logs to a text file in their groupings by iterating through your tags in a script. Pseudo code:

```
for (TAG in MYTAGS) {
    abd logcat -s TAG >> mylogfile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add custom tag in your UI Automator script:

```
private static final String TAG = "Script_Name";
Log.d(TAG, "message");
```

Write a simple batch script to collect logs and start it before you run your script:

```
adb logcat -c    //To clear previous logs
adb logcat -s Script_Name > Log.txt  //Saves your Script specific logs into Log.txt
```